# R- reshape irregular molten data frame by group that has missing values in another column

Tags: r, reshape

I have a large data frame that is grouped (column group in example data) into measurements that have taken place at the same time. Values (column value) were measured by 4 different devices (column device), but there was not necessarily a measurement of all 4 devices at the same time. My data looks like this

```
    group device value value.to.be.averaged
1     1      a    69                  173
2     1      b    75                  172
3     2      a    78                  173
4     2      c    69                  172
5     2      b    60                  173
6     2      d    62                  172
7     3      a    80                  173
8     3      c    63                  173
9     3      b    63                  172
```

which can be reproduced by this

```
my_data<-data.frame(group=c(rep(1:3, c(2,4,3))), 
           device=c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d", "a", "c", "b") , 
           value=sample(60:80,9,replace=T), value.to.be.averaged=sample(172:173,9,replace=T))
```

I need to bring device into column, keep the group number as row id and assign each exact measured value to the devices and if a device is missing in the group assign NA. There are other variables that can be simply averaged. The data should look like this afterwards.

```
   group a  b c  d value.to.be.averaged
1     1 77 68 NA NA      172
2     2 60 73 70 76      173
3     3 65 76 77 NA      172
```

Which can be reproduced by this

```
my_reshaped_data<-data.frame(group=c(1:3), a=c(77, 60, 65), b=c(68,73,76), c=c(NA, 70,77), d=c(NA, 76, NA), value.to.be.averaged=c(mean(172,173,173), 
                                                                                                             mean(rep(173,3)), mean(172,172,173)))
```

Since my data is hughe, computation time and computational ressource is an issue.
I found some examples with evenly siced groups but non with irregular groups. Any suggestions? Cheers, jannis

Comment: If you would convert `device` values to column. You would get 2 rows for each `group`. How come your out has one row for each `group`.

Comment: @sm925, it is one value measured per device in each group, which results in one row per group.

Comment: Yes, then your `value.to.be.averaged` is a problem which value to choose from that column. For example there's 173 and 172 for group 1. Why did you choose 172 in output?

Comment: These values should be averaged. Thats why i called it "value to be averaged". I wrote it in the decription of my problem before the table with the desired outcome. In the reproducible example, i calculated the mean of the three consecutive values. but maybe i did not make it clear enough. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tidyverse to convert the data from long to wide format. 
It automatically incorporates NA into the column when the device was not used for that group

```r
my_data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(average.values = mean(value.to.be.averaged)) %>%
  select(-value.to.be.averaged) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(., names_from = device, values_from = value)
```

Comment: He JCran, this seems like the perfect solution, but pivot_wider is not in the namespace of my tidyverse version.  After trying to download the development version of dplyr as well as updating and reinstalling a bunch of dependencies, it seems that github does not allow me to install more today: Error: Failed to install 'dplyr' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 403.
  API rate limit exceeded for 178.4.26.3.

Comment: Can you not install it from CRAN?

Comment: I am updating my R version right now. I am sure that this will do the trick. Thanks

Comment: It allmost did the trick, but y still have one row for each match id, eg. three match ids "4" result in 3 rows with id 4 and NA in device. here is an example: my_reshaped_data<-data.frame(group=c(4,4,4), a=c(77, NA, NA), b=c(NA,73,NA), c=c(NA,NA,77), d=c(NA, NA, NA), value.to.be.averaged=c(mean(172,173,173), 
                                                                                                                 mean(rep(173,3)), mean(172,172,173)))

Comment: I want it to be like this: data.frame(group=4, a=77, b=73, c=77, d=NA, value.to.be.averaged=c(mean(172,173,173)))

Comment: Hi sorry for not reading the question carefully enough I think I now have produced an example for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dcast` from `data.table`:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, value.to.be.averaged := round(mean(value.to.be.averaged)), by = group]
 dcast(df, group + value.to.be.averaged ~ device)

 #     group value.to.be.averaged  a  b  c  d
 #1:     1                  172   69 75 NA NA
 #2:     2                  172   78 60 69 62
 #3:     3                  173   80 63 63 NA
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), device = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("a","b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), value = c(69L, 75L, 78L,69L, 60L, 62L, 80L, 63L, 63L), value.to.be.averaged = c(173L, 172L, 173L, 172L, 173L, 172L, 173L, 173L, 172L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: Yes! that did it! Thanks sm925!